# How to format a session variable in a bracket part

Tags: php, jquery, variables, session, tablesorter

I use tablesorter. in the page before i set a session cookie.

tablesorter has this part:

```
   $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', 'test'  ], true);
```

now i need the session variable where the word 'test' is, but i don't know how to format it...

is it like this:

```
  $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', ($_SESSION["favcoloor"]) ], true);
```

or like this:

```
 $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', '($_SESSION["favcoloor"])' ], true);
```

or like this:

```
  $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', $_SESSION["favcoloor"] ], true);
```

or

```
  $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', "$_SESSION["favcoloor"]" ], true);
```

i can not get it to work, please help me with the correct formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to echo the session variable from PHP into your jQuery code :)

```
$.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', '<?php echo $_SESSION["favcoloor"]; ?>' ], true);
```

If [PHP shorthand tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) are enabled, you can use this:

```
$.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', '<?=$_SESSION["favcoloor"];?>' ], true);
```

Comment: @tijnn if any answer satisfy your requirement as according to the question asked, then you must have to accept that answer. This will help other users if they encounter same type of problem as you.